# Replace a lib in Websphere 8.5 causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, websphere, classloader, application-server

For various reasons that temporarily stop me from doing a complete recompile and redeploy, I want to hot-swap a .jar library on an application in Websphere. I want to replace the library **xyz-1.7.jar** with a previous version number, **xyz-1.4.jar**.

I located the .jar file in

```
/AppServer/profiles/$AppServer/installedApps/$Cell/$App.ear/
```

and replaced it with a previous version, and then restarted the server using

```
./startServer.sh $myServer
```

Once it was up and running, I logged in to the app to find it throwing NoClassDefFoundErrors.

I enabled the Class Loading Trace setting in Websphere and discovered that neither version of the .jar lib is being loaded.

Have I changed the .jar lib in the correct place?

I know from some experience in Tomcat and JBoss, I would need to modify the unexploded .ear file instead of the exploded deployed directory, but Websphere is new to me. Is it possible to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: You *should* be able to replace the jar in App.ear/App.war/WEB-INF/lib. I'm not sure about jars at a higher level. Are your overwritten jar file permissions correct? Also, did you stopServer.sh before you startServer.sh?

Answer (score 1):

First check from console that the setting "Enterprise Applications > Appname > Class loading and update detection > **Reload classes when application files are updated**" is **enabled** and **Polling interval for updated files** is set to a positive value.

If not enable it and restart the application.

Then you can update the jar inside **installedApps** taking care about read file permissions.

However why don't you use "**Replace or add a single file**" as an Update option from WAS console? 
Just enter the relative path of the jar inside your EAR inside "**Specify the path beginning with the installed application archive file to the file to be replaced or added**" text filed and you are done.